# Send Crash report to server if ipad application crash?

Tags: ipad, ios5, crash, crash-reports

I am working on ipad application right now, we are using zendesk for all kinds of user feedback forms, i want to know if its possible for app installed on ipad to read the crash log(if any crash has occured earlier for the app) and send it to our zendesk server.

I know i can sync the crash reports with iTunes and ask user to send it later, but is there any alternative available ?

Any kind of leads ll be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at third-party libraries that provide more... elaborate information than the iTunes Connect reports. I'm not sure if you can export any information from them, however they provide pretty decent feedback when it comes to crash logs:

- [HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net/): the good thing about them is that they provide an app-store compatible version of their library
- [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com): pretty decent too, though I'm not sure if they provide any app store compatible versions
- [Apphance](http://www.apphance.com/): also a decent framework, has all-in fancy screenshot reporting and drawing, however they also don't provide an app store compatible version yet

Long story short, you should take a look at your needs. If you wish to have the reporting for Beta builds only check out Apphance or TestFlight. However if you need something that will be released to the app store - go for the HockeyApp.

Comment: well..i am not suppose to use any third party library(project requirement :( .. you have ny clue where i can start with ? reventing the wheel is not good idea, i know.. but i can't help with that..

Comment: Well then, all you can do is to write your own crash reporting tool then. Start by looking how the PLCrashReporter is written (it's open sourced), though you might get into some licensing problems here (if don't provide attribution that is).

Comment: yeah just saw.. its open source.. :)

Comment: The HockeyApp SDK is open source and uses PLCrashReporter under the hood by leveraging the QuincyKit SDK on top of it. There is an open source server for QuincyKit too with less features, if you don't want to go for the HockeyApp service. Beta testing is also available, either with HockeyApp and it's Open Source SDK HockeyKit, or the HockeyKit open source server. Note: I am one of the developers of all these.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the [TestFlight SDK](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/) or [QuincyKit](http://quincykit.net/) in your application. Then crash reports will be send automatically.

Comment: third party libraries are big NO as per project requirements